# How to download the latest version of Google Chrome enterprise edition using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, google-chrome

Is there a way to use PowerShell to get the latest build of Google Chrome enterprise?

Things I've tried:

- Inspecting the page for any generic URLs that could be reused, but they were just part of the website code that generated a different URL.
- Taking a look at browser dev tools to find the actual URL that gets generated. Unfortunately, that one includes a GUID. So it appears it's pointing to a specific build and I still cannot grab the latest build this way.

Have you got any experience with this? Does Google provide some fixed URL or an API for this?